# Widget Extension UnitTest Error: "Undefined Symbol: nominal type descriptor for [...]."

Tags: swift, unit-testing

I have a Widget Extension for my app with a struct `MyStruct` defined in my extension, with target membership `MyAppWidgetExtension`. I also have a UnitTesting target, in which I want to have UnitTests for my main App as well as for the WidgetExtension.

As soon as I add a file to the UnitTesting-target, which has a `var`/`let` of type `MyStruct`, e.g. `var foo: MyStruct?` (which is recognized by the compiler by `@testable import MyAppWidgetExtension` within this file), executing the UnitTests yields a compiler error: "Undefines symbol: nominal type descriptor for MyAppWidgetExtension.MyStruct".

Any idea what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a solution, which feels like a workaround, but does the job:

- Define `MyStruct`  as well in the main app target with target membership `MyApp`
- In the UnitTest use `@testable import MyApp` in order to be able to use `MyStruct` from the app target

Now the compiler does not complain anymore.